# Calculate average of ratings in array, then add field to original document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a documents that have a field called ratings.  This is an array of objects, each object containing userId and ratingValue

```
ratings: Array
 0: Object
  userId: "uidsample1"
  ratingValue: 5
 1: Object
  userId:"uidsample2"
  ratingValue:1.5
```

I want to do an aggregation pipeline to calculate the new average when one of the ratings in the array is updated or added. Then, I want to put that value in the document as a new field called averageRating.

I have tried unwinding, then $ add field of $avg : "ratings.ratingValue" but it adds to the unwinded documents and doesnt get the average. It looks something like this (not exactly since testing on compass)

```
db.test.aggregate{
  [
    {
    $unwind: {
    path: "$ratings"
    }
  },
  { 
    $addFields {
    averageRating: {
    $avg: "$ratings.ratingValue"
      }
    }

      }
    ]
  }
```

What's a good query structure for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't actually need to `$unwind` and `$group` to calculate the average, these operations are costly

you can simply `$addFields` with `$avg`

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {averageRating : {$avg : "$ratings.ratingValue"}}}
])
```

sample collection and aggregation

```
> db.t62.drop()
true

> db.t62.insert({data : {ratings : [{val : 1}, {val : 2}]}})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.t62.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c44d9719d56bf65be5ab2e6"), "data" : { "ratings" : [ { "val" : 1 }, { "val" : 2 } ] } }

> db.t62.aggregate([{$addFields : {avg : {$avg : "$data.ratings.val"}}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c44d9719d56bf65be5ab2e6"), "data" : { "ratings" : [ { "val" : 1 }, { "val" : 2 } ] }, "avg" : 1.5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$group` after `$unwind` as below to calculate the *averageRating*.  Aggregate is a read operation.  You need to update the doc afterward.

```
[
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$ratings'
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$_id', 
            'averageRating': {
                '$avg': '$ratings.ratingValue'
            }
        }
    }
]
```